# How to translate my .bashrc functions to Powershell equivalent?

Tags: powershell, function, alias

I now nothing about Powershell but I want to provide potential users of the application easier entry into a Docker Alpine bash session basically.

On Linux, I wrote these simple functions.

```
vidhop_stop() {
  docker stop "$(docker ps -a -q)"
  docker rm "$(docker ps -a -q)"
}

vidhop_start() {
  vidhop_stop 1>/dev/null
  docker run --name vidhop-docker \
    -v "$PWD/media:/vidhop" \
    -v "$PWD/vidhop/.bash_history":"/root/.bash_history" \
    -it vidhop-docker /bin/bash
}

vidhop_build() {
  [ ! -f Dockerfile ] && echo "this directory doesn't contain a Dockerfile" && return
  docker build -t vidhop-docker .
}

vidhop_build_no_cache() {
  [ ! -f Dockerfile ] && echo "this directory doesn't contain a Dockerfile" && return
  docker build --no-cache -t vidhop-docker .
}

vidhop() {
  [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "usage: vidhop start | stop  | build" && return
  [ "$1" = "start" ] && vidhop_start && return
  [ "$1" = "stop" ] && vidhop_stop && return
  [ "$1" = "build" ] && vidhop_build && return
  echo "'$1' is not a valid argument, use 'vidhop [ start | stop | build ]'"
}
```

With those functions defined, I can run `vidhop start` command inside the Linux terminal, which triggers a `docker run` command.

A translation of that would be awesome and a word or two on how to install these functions in Powershell (from new users).

Comment: Since a lot of PowerShell coders do not know nothing about bash it might be better to explain what your code actually does. Often it does not make that much sense to translate one to one from one scripting langeuage to another. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Ok, I added a paragraph of context after the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### .bashrc equivalent in Powershell

(Copied from https://superuser.com/a/1009553/633101)

`~/.bashrc` => `%userprofile%\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Type the following command to create the file:
`New-item –type file –force $profile`

A file Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 will be created in C:\Users<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\ for PowerShell 5 and older or C:\Users<username>\Documents\PowerShell\ for PowerShell 6 Core (this folder will be automatically created).

Then edit this file and you can add personalized PowerShell functions or load modules or snap-ins...

Now when you run your powershell console, Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 will be triggered.

### Startup scripts inside `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

```
Function Prompt {"$(Get-Location) $ "}

Function Vidhop-Stop() {
     docker stop "$(docker ps -a -q)"
     docker rm "$(docker ps -a -q)"
}

Function Vidhop-Start() {
    Vidhop-Stop; clear
    docker run --name vidhop-docker -v $PWD/media:/vidhop -v $PWD/vidhop/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history -it vidhop-docker /bin/bash
}

Function Vidhop-Build() {
    docker build -t vidhop-docker .
}

Function Vidhop-BuildNoCache() {
    docker build --no-cache -t vidhop-docker .
}

Function dclear {
    docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
    docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
}
```

### Result

After you open a new Powershell terminal, you should be able to call `Vidhop-Start`, `Vidhop-Stop` etc.